# How to find the minimum values of a query's column

Tags: mysql, sql

how do you find the minimum value of a column of a query?

My table X's data looks like this:

```
(id, something, userId, something) values

('R001','something','U0006','something'),
('R002','something','U0014','something'),
('R001','something','U0006','something'),
('R002','something','U0015','something'),
('R003','something','U0003','something'),
('R001','something','U0014','something'),
('R001','something','U0002','something');
```

My query, looks like this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT userId, COUNT( id ) AS count
FROM X
GROUP BY userId
ORDER BY count DESC
```

and this query returns:

```
userId  count
U0006   2
U0014   2
U0002   1
U0003   1
U0015   1
```

How do I get the minimum values of count in the query, bearing in mind that there are multiple minimum values?

The return I want from the query would look like this:

```
userId
U0002
U0003
U0015
```

Thanks, in advance :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this using a `having` clause:

```
SELECT userId, COUNT( id ) AS count
FROM X
GROUP BY userId
HAVING COUNT(id) = (SELECT MIN(cnt)
                    FROM (SELECT COUNT(id) as cnt
                          FROM X
                          GROUP BY userId
                         ) xx
                   );
```

Using `select distinct` with `group by` is almost always redundant.

Comment: #1248 - Every derived table must have its own alias.

Comment: @user3357642 . . . That would be `xx`.